# Create a cookie that is accesibe from JS only and no being sent with every request/

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, salt

Is it possible to create a cookie that will stay available for the client's browser but won't be sent with the header of each request?

I want to send session salt via HTTPS and then let the user encrypt with it and send the encrypted data via HTTP with each request,

Is there a way not to send the salt with the encrypted data?

Comment: that is against the protocol

Comment: Look into HTTPS-only cookies. Not sure if they're available from javascript, though. Perhaps `localStorage` would be a better option for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) or sessionStorage. Note that polyfills for this feature usually follow a cookie-based approach, but going with a purely localStorage or sessionStorage solution will cause no data to be sent with the headers on each page load.

Comment: Is there any cross-browser solution?

Comment: It is largely cross-browser already, but localStorage only becomes available starting IE8. Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect availability.

Answer (score 0):

A cookie will be sent on every request as that is what they are for. localStorage is what you need, but is unavailable for older browsers. 
If you require it to work in an older browser you can try a few things.

1: store the code in session on the server

2: pass the code in the querystring to other pages

3: make a full ajax page so you dont have to switch sites

4: create a hidden frame to store the data (worst option)